# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimer, uicollectionviewcell

So I've read other questions about the error in the title, and I've tried their solutions, but they do not work for me.

In `viewDidLoad()`, I have these two timers:

```
dayCountTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(DateMenuViewController.dayCount(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
daySinceTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(DateMenuViewController.daysSinceOrUntil(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

They call these two methods:

```
// For dayCountLabel.text
func dayCount (dayCount: String) -> String{
    let day = dayCount
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)!
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    let difference = String("\(abs(diffDateComponents.day))")
    return difference
}

// For daySinceOrUntilLabel.text
func daysSinceOrUntil (daySince: String) -> String {
    let day = daySince
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day)!
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

    if date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending  {
        let text: String = "Days Until"
        return text
    } else if date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
        let text: String = "Days Since"
        return text
    } else {
       return "Days"
    }

}
```

And are used within a `UICollectionViewCell` in the following way.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

cell.dayCountLabel.text = dayCount(Globals.datesArray[indexPath.item])
cell.daySinceOrUntilLabel.text = daysSinceOrUntil(Globals.datesArray[indexPath.item])
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: The argument to your `dayCount` and `daysSinceOrUntil` functions is an NSTimer, not a string. Also, there is no point returning a value from a function that is invoked by a timer. It seems that you want to use the update your cells. In that case you need to write another function to update the cells. You can't use these functions

Comment: I need those functions to update every second though?

Comment: Those functions return the values you are displaying in your cells. They don't update the cells. You need to write a new function that gets all of the currently visible cells and then calls these functions to get the new value and then updates the cell. That is the function that needs to be executed by the timer.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to achieve that?